# Python - how can i format a long output string?

Tags: python, linux

I'm using imdbpie module to query Imdb and get a movie titles.

```
from imdbpie import Imdb
imdb = Imdb()
film = str(imdb.search_for_title('some_title'))
tit = re.sub(r'[^\w]|year|title|imdb_id|tt[0-9]{7}', ' ', film)
print( tit )
```

I stripped unwanted patterns and get the output :

```
2015                     The Merchant  Gaekju 2015         2015                     Murderers  Mobsters   Madmen Vol  2  Assassination in the 20th Century         1993                     The Manzai 2015 Pre Masters         2015                     The 2015 World Series         2015                     2015 Foster Farms Bowl         2015                     2015 Nephilim  Monsters   Giants Conference         2015                     2015 The Disaster Diaries  2015 L Agenda Des Cataclysmes         2015                     The Lobster         2015                     Brooklyn Lobster         2005                     The Oscar Nominated Short Films 2015  Animation         2015                     The Oscar Nominated Short Films 2015  Live Action         2015                     La langosta azul         1954                     The Fresh Lobster         1948                     The Lobster         2013                     The Oscar Nominated Short Films 2015  Documentary         2015                     A Visit to a Crab and Lobster Factory         1913                     BBC Election Debate 2015  The Reaction         2015                     Easter Bowl 2011  Beneath the Surface         2011                     The Lonesome Lobster         2010
```

String is a line and contains random vars "year" and "Movie Title". 
I'd like format this output like this :

2015                     The Merchant  Gaekju 2015
2015                     Murderers  Mobsters   Madmen Vol  2  Assassination in the 20th Century
2015                     The 2015 World Series
2015                     Foster Farms Bowl
         2015                     Nephilim  Monsters   Giants Conference
         2015                     The Disaster Diaries
 2015 L Agenda Des Cataclysmes
...
...
...

I've changed code a bit and add a new line character into output string and basically got what i needed, but maybe is there is other, more elegant way to do that.

```
tit = re.sub(r'[^\w'+rlist+']|year|title|imdb_id|tt[0-9]{7}', ' ', film)
ntit = re.sub(r'}', '\n', tits) 
f = open('titles.txt', 'wt')
print( ntit, file=f )
f.close()
```

$ cat titles.txt
The National Lottery Stars 2015         2015
           The Merchant  Gaekju 2015         2015
          Murderers  Mobsters   Madmen Vol  2  Assassination in the 20th Century         1993
          The Manzai 2015 Pre Masters         2015
           The 2015 World Series         2015
           Foster Farms Bowl         2015

Comment: Why does your first line of desired output have a year at the end as well?

Comment: Tried using regex?

Comment: To me...this does not look to have a regular pattern to develop a method or function for it, my suggestion is to try fix the output generate by the source function to have a better output than the one you posted..

Comment: i updated my question with more details

Answer (score 0):

It's messy but there is a pattern. It's the year, followed by 21 spaces, followed by the title, followed by 9 spaces, and then it starts again. Proof:

```
>>> import re
>>> map(len, re.findall(r'\s{4,}', s))
[21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9, 21, 9]
```

However, relying on these exact numbers is not wise. Let's just say that there's large gaps alternating with medium gaps, and capture them like that:

```
>>> from pprint import *
>>> pprint(re.findall(r'(.+?)\s{15,}(.+?)\s{5,}', s))
[('2015', 'The Merchant  Gaekju 2015'),
 ('2015',
  'Murderers  Mobsters   Madmen Vol  2  Assassination in the 20th Century'),
 ('1993', 'The Manzai 2015 Pre Masters'),
 ('2015', 'The 2015 World Series'),
 ('2015', '2015 Foster Farms Bowl'),
 ('2015', '2015 Nephilim  Monsters   Giants Conference'),
 ('2015', '2015 The Disaster Diaries  2015 L Agenda Des Cataclysmes'),
 ('2015', 'The Lobster'),
 ('2015', 'Brooklyn Lobster'),
 ('2005', 'The Oscar Nominated Short Films 2015  Animation'),
 ('2015', 'The Oscar Nominated Short Films 2015  Live Action'),
 ('2015', 'La langosta azul'),
 ('1954', 'The Fresh Lobster'),
 ('1948', 'The Lobster'),
 ('2013', 'The Oscar Nominated Short Films 2015  Documentary'),
 ('2015', 'A Visit to a Crab and Lobster Factory'),
 ('1913', 'BBC Election Debate 2015  The Reaction'),
 ('2015', 'Easter Bowl 2011  Beneath the Surface'),
 ('2011', 'The Lonesome Lobster')]
```

The `pprint` is only for output formatting here. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/mX5uK6/1) is an explanation of the regex.